# How can I implement tangent distance for k-nearest neighbor in python/scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance, k-nn, linear-algebra

My ultimate aim is to have a function which I can feed into scikit-learn's `NearestNeighbor` class as a custom `metric` parameter.

## Existing packages

I have been researching existing libraries for a while.

The only thing I found was [this KMeans package](https://github.com/ComeOnGetMe/KMeans-with-custom-metric-function-and-multithreading), for python 2 and based on implementing a C library.  I could neither load it in with `ctypes` nor convert it into an executable with `gcc`.

I also found this [other C code](https://cse.iitk.ac.in/users/cs365/2013/hw1/td.c) and this [Matlab script](https://cse.iitk.ac.in/users/cs365/2013/hw1/tangent_d.m) but with similar results.

## Implementation

I also looked into a few papers, to see if I can implement it by myself. For instance, based on [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231964276_Numerical_linear_algebra_in_data_mining) I understand that the main thing I need to do is to calculate the tangent matrix. But, I do not understand

- how do I define $s(p, \alpha)$ and especially
- how do I calculate the derivatives in python.

I would be glad for any help, comment, whatsoever.

## Update

As suggested, I raised the following related issues/requests:

- [ComeOnGetMe](https://github.com/ComeOnGetMe/KMeans-with-custom-metric-function-and-multithreading/issues/1)
- [Scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12711)

## Update 2

@ComeOnGetMe rewrote his code so it can be used along the scikit-learn specifications ([example code](https://github.com/ComeOnGetMe/KMeans-with-custom-metric-function-and-multithreading/blob/master/sklearn_custom_metric.py)). Many thanks for that! Nonetheless, when I tried to use it in scikit-learn [it underperformed and was very slow](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12711), so there is further work needed with that.

Since then I also found a more [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340353/distance-between-hyperplanes/13352507#13352507) for code implementation, although based on the C code already mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just repeat my reply under the original issue in case anybody is looking for the answer here.

#### The direct answer to the issue:

I can't really recall how I used this code 2 years ago. But I got it working with two steps:

1. Build the shared library with `gcc -fPIC -shared st.c -o ts.so`.
2. Change the .so path in tangentDistance.py to the absolute path of the ts.so file.

I have just updated the code so that you can run it directly after compiling the .so file in the root directory.

#### A bit of comment on this repo:

Clearly this library is not well designed and filled with so much hardcodes. You can't really use it if you are not doing exactly the same task as I was doing: k-means clustering on MNIST dataset. If you want it to be more general and better fit your purposes just let me know.

Comment: Great, many thanks for this! I try to build the shared library, but got another error message: `gcc: error: st.c: No such file or directory // gcc: fatal error: no input files  // compilation terminated.` I suppose I would need to reinstall gcc for this? I continue to investigate and will get back if have some results.

Comment: By 'root' I mean the root of the repository where the ```st.c``` file is located.

Comment: BTW You don't need to compile it since I have pushed the .so file. Just pull from the repo and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for this. I detailed my experiences on your KMeans package's github page.

Answer (score 1):

ComOnGetMe's [KMeans tangent distance metric](https://github.com/ComeOnGetMe/KMeans-with-custom-metric-function-and-multithreading) looks good, if it didn't work for you initially you should fork it and work on the code. I would contact him directly, he probably would have insight for you. Scikit-learn doesn't have a [distance metric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric) for [tangent distances](http://web.csulb.edu/~jchang9/files/tandis_paper.pdf) but the documentation states you can call a user-defined distance (all be it with overhead).

[Contributing code](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html) might be a good direction to go if you would want to contact scikit-learn's developers and there are a couple of researchers with published papers implementing tangent distance as a metric, so you could have luck there too.

Comment: Thanks for this! I raised these issues as you suggested (see the links at the end), but to fork/contribute I still would need to understand how should I do it.

[1]: https://github.com/ComeOnGetMe/KMeans-with-custom-metric-function-and-multithreading/issues/1
[2]: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12711

Comment: The paper I linked by some researchers who implemented it explains it pretty throughly. Basically it's a local linearity metric that scales using the jacobian determinant and uses a tangent transform. If you're familiar with manifold learning and take a look at [Tangent_space](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) you can see the theoretical implications to distance metrics. Contributing to the code is more-or-less a process of studying it and getting it to work, which isn't something I can help out with on stackexchange, but I hope you do get it working!